# Firebase crashlytics error: Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskProvider'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-fabric, firebase-crash-reporting

I am trying to update fabric to Firebase crashlytics .

I followed their starting guide given [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android)

The error I am getting are below:

[image]
(build.gradle) module-level:

[image]

I am using Gradle version: 4.6
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

Let me know if needed more info.

Answer (score 2):

OK, Updated Android studio to the latest stable - `4.1`

Updated Kotlin to the latest version - `1.14.10`

Here's my build gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}
```

Also, gradle version should be `6.5` in `gradle-wrapper.proporties` file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

It's all working now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my project is still in java, should I still add kotlin dependency ?

Comment: Updated android studio to version 4.1: Added above dependencies which you mentioned, I have tried to delete all the gradle files then download gradle from scratch, tried Invalidate Catch / Restart functionality, doesn't work. I am getting these errors:

Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.reporting.internal.TaskReportContainer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/gradle/api/Task;)V'
org.gradle.api.reporting.internal.TaskReportContainer.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/gradle/api/Task;)V

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: @asadinside kotlin dependency is relevant if you use it, otherwise i guess not.

Comment: @asadinside another thing, use this guide for installing firebase crashlytics, it seems like the upgrade guide has a few missing points
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

Comment: I fixed the issue, actually problem was using correct versions (plugins, gradle).

Configs I used: 
- gradle:3.4.3
- google-services:4.3.3'
- firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
- distributionUrl=gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
- firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
- firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'.